# Only output grep results

Tags: grep, curl, stdout

I'm trying to `grep` some curl content however I'm still getting curl output even though I'm piping it via grep.

E.g.

```
curl -svo /dev/null <some url>   | grep <some text>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you mean you're getting output that's *not* matching the grep? Are they long lines that match somewhere unexpectedly?

Comment: You're aware that options `-s` and `-v` have more or less opposite effects, right?

Comment: They're misleading but not opposite. `-v` outputs additional curl output. `-s` prevents the progress bar header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pipe only the `stdout` to `grep`, but your `curl` puts out errors to `stderr` which are printed without passing the `grep`. If you want the `stderr` to be filtered, too, redirect it to `stdout` first.

Comment: Hardly need to take a wild guess. It's pretty obvious how to fill in the blanks. Here's an example if you're struggling: `curl -svo /dev/null https://www.google.com   | grep google`

Comment: @SnowCrash Thank you. I didn't try. Removed the _wild guess_ from my answer, as I obviously guess right.

Comment: @SnowCrash If your question is solved, please close it by marking it as answered